# ngGrid Clear Sorting Data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I would like to be able to remove the sorting data from ng-grid. In the example below, I would like to remove the sorting when I press 'Sort'.

I have been reading the ng-grid.js and I found a function called ClearSortingData(). I don't know how to implement it, or if it's supposed to do what I want.

```
self.clearSortingData = function (col) {
    if (!col) {
        angular.forEach(self.lastSortedColumns, function (c) {
            c.sortDirection = "";
            c.sortPriority = null;
        });
        self.lastSortedColumns = [];
    } else {
        angular.forEach(self.lastSortedColumns, function (c) {
            if (col.index !== c.index) {
                c.sortDirection = "";
                c.sortPriority = null;
            }
        });
        self.lastSortedColumns[0] = col;
        self.lastSortedColumns.length = 1;
    }
};
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9INnbNs9fzytj5wxASi?p=preview) example. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem when i needed to clear sorting and filter away. For clearing the sort I used this in a function which is working with external sort (didnt try with javascript sorting).

```
if ($scope.gridOptions) {
  $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.config.sortInfo = { fields:[], directions: [], columns:[] };
    angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.lastSortedColumns, function (c) {
      c.sortPriority = null;
      c.sortDirection = "";
  });
  $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.lastSortedColumns = [];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Kudos to Pratik S below for the missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the above answer, one thing missing that may land you in error is

```
 $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.config.sortInfo = { fields:[], directions: [], columns:[] };
```

You've missed doing this to initialize the column, which means on resort the console will show trying to access length of undefined and sorting won't work.

Comment: Good catch Pratik, I've edited the original answer to include your correction.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the external sortInfo to handle , you need to add

> > $scope.sortInfo = $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.config.sortInfo

to make the ngGrid internal sortInfo and external sortInfo consistently